# Is it possible to install sonata on symfony 3.2

Tags: symfony, composer-php, sonata

I get this error with composer require sonata-project/propel-admin-bundle dev-master:

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for sonata-project/propel-admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/propel-admin-bundle[dev-master].
    - sonata-project/propel-admin-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.3 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.10, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Is there any possible way to get sonata to work on symfony 3.2? Is it possible to ignore composer requirement errors somehow and then fix compatibility errors myself?

Comment: Please show your composer.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SonataPropelAdminBundle is not compatible with Symfony 3.x. As you can see in the error it requires SonataAdminBundle `~2.3` and only versions > 3.x of SonataAdminBundle are compatible with Symfony 3.x